# Can't insert ApplicationUser ID into my context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I am using code-first with MVC5 and I have designed some of my models to contain a reference to ApplicationUser. The idea is to save the user you created the row on important business objects.

e.g.
model:

```
public class Guest
{
    ..... other properties
    public ApplicationUser CreatedByUser { get; set; }


}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(GuestVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       .....
        return View(model);
    }
    // Initialize a new instance of the data model and set its properties
    Guest guest = new Guest()
    {
        ......
        CreatedByUser = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())
    };
    db.Guests.Add(guest);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

It picks up my user correctly, if I put a breakpoint before db.Guests.Add(guest); I can see the correct info in there.

Here is the OnModelCreating

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id).Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(u => new { u.UserId, u.LoginProvider, u.ProviderKey });
}
```

However, it then fails with the following error

> The member with identity 'Project.DAL.Guest_CreatedByUser' does not exist in the metadata collection.

I have put all my user defined models in a different context. Perhaps that is the problem...

Help! :)

Comment: can you post your OnModelCreating configuration for Guest

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to reference identity models, they need to be in the same context. One option is to have your app context inherit from IdentityDbContext. That has some issues if you try to separate out the data layer. Otherwise you could do a separate lookup. [MVC5 Identity + multiple context in EntityFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807810/mvc5-identity-multiple-context-in-entityframework)

Comment: If you inherit from IdentityDbContext you don't need the OnModelCreating code from above - that is handled automatically. Same for DbSets - not needed. Just define a relationship from your entity into ApplicationUser.